# I am building a spelling game in visual studio, but I don't know how to check the users input with my pre-coded 'database' of words

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am currently building a spelling game in Visual Studio Express 2012 and I need help. I have already coded all the words that are going to be there, and a random number generator. The number generator will be invisible in the final product but basically every number corresponds to a word. The code is something like this:

```
Dim r as New Random r.next(1,21)
If lblRandomNumber.text="1" then txtRandomWord.text="Adduct"
```

I have coded for 20 words, using the same code. My problem now is that I don't know how to check the users input with the predefined words, and that is what I'm asking for your help with. I know my code will work because when I inserted a new textbox, used the same code

```
(if lblRandomNumber.text="1" then txtUserInput.text= "adduct"), and then said coded "if txtUserInput.text=txtRandomWord.text Then msgbox.text("well done").
```

After clicking the word generate button a few times (to get the number 1) a message box finally came up and said "well done".
My question is, how would I return the users input to the computer and have the computer check that input with the other words in my "database" of words.
I know it is not a database of words but I don't know what else to call it.
Not all of my code is precisely right here as I don't currently have access to my program. If you could help me out I would be very thankful,
Oisin.